# Listing available Bluetoothdevices in ListView but ListView isn't shown

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

I want to create a app that can send data with Bluetooth to another device. First I made a Button to turn Bluetooth on and off. That works smoothly! Now I included a ListView that should list available yet unpaired devices, but the ListView is not showing. I searched for a solution but I coulnd't find anything. I don't get any Event Log and I don't know what I should do. I tried many different things but in the end my app just kept crashing. Here is my code:

```
<Button
    android:text="On/Off"
    android:id="@+id/btnONOFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvNewDevices"
    android:layout_width="162dp"
    android:layout_height="196dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btnONOFF"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="3dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="96dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";

BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

public ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();       //hold BluetoothDevices that are discovered
public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;
public ListView lvNewDevices;

private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver3 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.");

        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)){
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);   //throws an parcelable extra device in the former device
            mBTDevices.add(device);     //stores the new device
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + device.getName()+ ": " + device.getAddress());
            mDeviceListAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices);   //attach DeviceList to DeviceListAdapter
            lvNewDevices.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter);        //set the List to AdapterList
            //remember device_adapter_view.xml in res -> layout!
        }
    }
};

protected void onDestroy(){
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called");
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver3);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnONOFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnONOFF);
    lvNewDevices = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNewDevices);
    mBTDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

    btnONOFF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.");       //tell when Button is clicked
            enableDisableBT();
        }
    });
}

/* if Bluetooth is enabled and Button is clicked, Bluetooth will turn off
   if Bluetooth is not enabled and Button is clicked, Bluetooth will turn on
 */
public void enableDisableBT() {

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {      //means device has no Bluetooth Adapter
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.");
        finish();
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {     //if Bluetooth is not enabled
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.");
        Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);
    }
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {      //if Bluetooth is enabled
        Log.d(TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.");
        mBluetoothAdapter.disable();        //disable Bluetooth
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    //first cancel discovery because it's very memory intensive
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
}
```

}

The DeviceListAdapter class

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices;
private int mViewResourceId;

public DeviceListAdapter(Context context, int tvResourceId, ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> devices){
    super(context, tvResourceId, devices);
    this.mDevices = devices;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = tvResourceId;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
    BluetoothDevice device = mDevices.get(position);

    if(device != null){
        TextView deviceName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceName);
        TextView deviceAdress = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDeviceAddress);

        if(deviceName != null){
            deviceName.setText(device.getName());
        }
        if(deviceAdress != null){
            deviceAdress.setText(device.getAddress());
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

I made a BluetoothChat Tutorial because I never programmed Bluetooth before. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

In your `onReceive` you have to add the new bluetooth device in your adapter’s list and then call the `notifyDataChanged()` and not create the adapter each time a device is found

**UPDATED**
You can create a set method in your adapter where you set the updated list after adding the new device and then call the `adapter.notifyDataChanged()`

Also where is the code you start the discovery? Does `onReceive` ever gets triggered?

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answer!
Doesn't `onReceive` get triggered with `final String action = intent.getAction();` ?
Do I need a new method for `adapter.notifyDataChanged()` or can I just put it at the end of the BoradcastReceiver?

Comment: I complemented `lvNewDevices.setAdapter(adapter);`and `lvNewDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                //adapter.getItem(position).getLiked(true);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });` in `onCreate` but now my app keeps on crashing.